# Getting the average within specific numbers in an array

Tags: java

I have a list of `values[] =  3 4 6 3 4 5 10 7 4 5 3 10 4 9`. Given a number, the code calculates the average around the neighbors of that number. For instance, we start with 9 wich is in position 7, then display the positions `i` in `values` that meet condition `value[i] > 9`. Then calculate the average of the five numbers around that number, that is, the number itself, 2 previous number and the 2 following numbers.

```
//The average of the 7th and 12th values is computed
average(7th)= (4 + 5 + 10 + 7 + 4 )/5 = 6
average(12th)= (5 + 3+ 10 + 4 + 9)/5 = 6.5
if  (values > 9)
    show index
else 
    changes (if false it shows the position)
```

I will like to be assisted with the code as I want to apply these to large data.  Thanks in advance

```java
//the constructive computation structure     
public class calch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int [] values = {3,4,6,3,4,5,10,7,4,5,3,10,4,9};
        for (int i =0; i < values.length; i ++){
            double average = 0; 

            //How do I compute the average here: calculate the average of the five numbers around that number , that is, the number itself, 2 previous number and the 2 following numbers
            if ( (values[i] > 9) && (average > 9) ) {
                 System.out.println("True changes  " + values[i]);
            } else if ((values[i] > 9) && (average < 9)){
                System.out.println (" False Changes " + values[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of 7 and 12 and I am getting nothing because I am unable to compute the average of the condition mentioned above. the matlab code for the problem is below:

```
values =[3 4 6 3 4 5 10 7 4 5 3 4];
window=ones(1,5)/5; avg=conv(values,window,'same');
true_changes=find( values>9 & avg>9 ); false_changes=find( values>9 & avg<=9 );
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to read. Please [edit] and improve it.

Comment: something like, for each number greater then 9, calculate the average of the five numbers *around* that number , that is, the number itself, 2 previous number and the 2 following numbers?

Comment: @Carlos I have edited it

Comment: it was a question... but is now answered. if you want the index of found values, you must print it (instead of only the value): e.g. `System.out.println("True changes  " + values[i] + " at " + (i+1));` - but there is no average calculation or printing at all in your code

Comment: @Carlos. Thanks for your swift response. The problem is I want to  calculate the average of the five numbers around that number , that is, the number itself, 2 previous number and the 2 following numbers. How do I go about that. thanks

Comment: to access the number at that position you use `values[i]`, the previous one is `values[i-1]` or following is `values[i+1]`.... sum all 5 and divide by `5.0` (`.0` since we do **not** want integer division)

Comment: and note that coded data does not match question data - coded data need caution regarding index since the last value is `> 9` and  has no 2 numbers to the right

Comment: @Carlos I have adjusted and edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to access surrounding 5 number like this `values[i-2]+...+values[i+2]`. Moreover, you should take care of the case in which your input data is not in correct form with your coded logic. For example:

> If your array is {12,4,5,9,7,8,13} in this case you'll get `IndexOutOfBoundException`

I have took care of this case in the code below:

```
public class calch 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
        int [] values = {3,4,6,3,4,5,10,7,4,5,3,10,4,9};
        for (int i =0; i < values.length; i ++)
        {
            // you can just use one "if" for checking "values[i]>9"
            // Added some checks so thta you wont get "IndexOutOfBoundsException"
            if((values[i] > 9) && (i>1) && (i<values.length-2))
            {
                double average = (double)(values[i-2]+values[i-1]+values[i]+values[i+1]+values[i+2])/5; 

                //System.out.println(average);  for debugging
                if (average > 9)
                    System.out.println("True changes  " + values[i]);
                else if (average < 9)
                    System.out.println("False Changes " + values[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                // ... I do't know what to do if data is not in correct form
                // that is if you last element of array is >9
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the average this way:

```
if (values[i] > 9) {
    int sum = values[i];
    double d = 1.0;
    if ((i - 1) > 0) {
        sum += values[i - 1];
        d += 1.0;
    }
    if ((i - 2) > 0) {
        sum += values[i - 2];
        d += 1.0;
    }
    if ((i + 1) < values.length) {
        sum += values[i + 1];
        d += 1.0;
    }
    if ((i + 2) < values.length) {
        sum += values[i + 2];
        d += 1.0;
    }

    double avg = sum / d;
}
```